# Copy, extract and launch a script upon Ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, automation, ubiquity

I want to modify the Ubuntu kernel or boot files or whatever necessary to do the following at the Ubuntu installation moment or just right after :

1. Copy a tar file and put it under `/home`
2. Extract that file
3. Access the directory after the extraction
4. Launch a script

I have noticed that during the Ubuntu installation there is a step called “copying files”. So I thought I can edit the code behind that to copy, extract my package then launch a script within that package as well.

Is this possible ?

I have tried to do the above actions using a pre-seed file. I used ubiquity/success_command and d-i preseed/late_command at the end of my preseed file and for some reason both go unnoticed.

```
enter d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target cp /cdrom/dev-master.tar.gz /target/home/; \
in-target cd  /target/home; \
in-target tar -zxvf /target/home/dev-master.tar.gz; \
in-target cd /home/dev-master/; \
in-target sh SCRIPT 


ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
in-target cp /cdrom/dev-master.tar.gz /target/home/; \
in-target cd  /target/home; \ 
in-target tar -zxvf /target/home/dev-master.tar.gz; \ 
in-target cd /home/dev-master/; \ 
in-target sh SCRIPT
```

What to do to accomplish the above actions ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please look at using `systemd` to access the different `run levels` and remember `file system` won't be available till certain stages in the installation...

Comment: So I have to use systemd to edit file system to do the above actions ? can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: You want the file to act when `/home` is available from your post...

Comment: You want the file to act when `/home` is available from your post... You create a `systemd service` and run a script via that service

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is 2 years late, I hope you already found the answer. But, for anyone who is coming here let me share whats worked for me. I used Debian but I think works for ubuntu.

The problem here is here:

```
in-target cp /cdrom/dev-master.tar.gz /target/home/; \
```

`in-target` means in installed operation system folder tree.
`/cdrom` does not belong to the OS that just had been installed. `/cdrom` is where the `iso` is monted on the installation system. So you can remove the `in-target` parameter:

```
cp /cdrom/dev-master.tar.gz /target/home/; \
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer even though the post is old. I hope this would be helpful for other people.

Comment: Thanks for saving me some time with Debian Buster.

Comment: I will tried that ASAP on bullseye